# Ubuntu machine can't make outgoing WAN connections

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-interface

I have an Ubuntu machine on my LAN into which I can connect via SSH. Trying to run `apt update` fails:

> W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2620:2d:4000:1::19). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) 
> ... 
> Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (185.125.190.36), connection timed out

Since I can ssh in, clearly the network is at least *partially* functional. I can also ping my router successfully and do DNS lookups (because I am hosting an AdGuard DNS on my LAN):

```
$ ping zombo.com
PING zombo.com (50.28.52.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- zombo.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1029ms
```

Other machines are able to access the WAN without issue, though:

```
$ ping 50.28.52.163
PING 50.28.52.163 (50.28.52.163) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 50.28.52.163: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=234 ms
64 bytes from 50.28.52.163: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=122 ms
^C
--- 50.28.52.163 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 122.004/178.146/234.288/56.142 ms
```

This machine is connected via ethernet (whereas all other devices are wifi), in case it's relevant. The relevant output of `ip addr` shows:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 28:d2:44:8d:36:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.20/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 2499sec preferred_lft 2499sec
    inet6 fe80::2ad2:44ff:fe8d:36d4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What might cause a Linux device (Ubuntu in particular) to be able to access the LAN but not the WAN? I don't have any configuration in my router (eg, QoS) that treats any device differently.